# How to configure/test DPDK as software firewall

Tags: networking, firewall

I have started exploring DPDK setup in Ubuntu. I am able to bind ports with DPDK drivers. I use Ubunutu 16.xx version in a virtual machine where the host is Windows 10. I want to use this vm as a DPDK based firewall for a  POC., I also tried testpmd, l2 fwd, Ip pipeline applications are compiled and working. But I am unable to proceed on testing on these sample applications.

I come from application development, I usually use wireshark to debug the network traffic and validate IP address and port numbers. In DPDK, there are ports with MAC address. But there is no concept of IP address.

DPDK firewall would be used as gateway device and will be connected to internet, LAN, DMZ setup as well. Just want to know basics as How we can deploy DPDK firewall without IP address? How will it receive packets? How do I send test packets from other machines to DPDK firewall for testing purpose using ping or scapy when IP is not assigned.

I miss some basic concepts in networking.

Would be great if someone provides good reference or inputs to clarify the same.

Comment: Since 16.04 is EOL in April this year you may want to use 18.04 or 20.04

Comment: Sure. Will go with 20.04. Thanks for inputs. Then my main concern is understanding on basic concepts on networking with respect to DPDK based firewall

Comment: @vijay are there any updates? based on the last discussion can you please update the question with the actual requirement or question? Current one states` know basics as How we can deploy DPDK firewall without IP address?`. But DPDK firewall ip_pipelien example does not work without IP address, you can always modify the same to reflect MAC, VLAN, QinQ etc,